# Is it rude or odd for a recruiter not to supply further job details when asked?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, job-search, recruitment

I've had an interaction with a recruiter that I found slightly odd and off-putting, but I can't make up my mind as to whether I'm reading too much into it or not. Any advice would be much appreciated.

**Background**
I've been working as a freelance web developer for 5-10 years. This year I have the intention to move from freelance work, into a permanent role. I'm in the UK.

**Situation**
A recruiter contacted me via a popular online career site.

**Recruiter first message**

> I have a really good <web developer> position at an excellent company based in <your town>.
> From your profile, your background seems like a perfect fit for the position - would you be open to a new role, and if so would you like some more information on it?

**My reply**

> I would be very interested to hear some more information about the role.

**Recruiter response**

> Thanks for your reply, from your profile your background does seem ideal - do you have a CV that you could send over, so that I can get a better feel for your background?

(Message text edited slightly for brevity)

I found this response to be a bit off putting. The Recruiter has already stated I could be a perfect fit, with the information they already have, and (more importantly) didn't actually provide any details about the position.

Basically I expected my reply of "I want the details you offered", to result in a response of "here are some more details".

Am I being unreasonable in finding this exchange slightly rude/unprofessional, and should I broach the topic with the recruiter?

Additionally should I send over my CV or press for more details about the role?

Comment: Sounds like a scripted introduction and response.

Comment: That happens to me all the time on LinkedIn. I typically ask them for the job description and requirements etc. Some recruiters do send that information, others ask for more information from me.

Comment: They are often just canvassing for cv’s to fill their database by you supplying your cv for a post that may or may not exist.

Comment: Give the recruiter a second chance to come up with a real offer, and if there's none, report them on the website.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it rude or odd for a recruiter not to supply further job details when asked?

I don't know that it's rude, but it's likely no specific position exists. They could be straight with you and say:

> I am collecting CVs that contain certain keywords, and yours has at least one of those words. Could you send it to me in case I someday find a matching position?

But that doesn't sound nearly as good, and you are much less likely to respond to that.

So I would reply with that in mind. If you are looking for something specific soon, you can withhold your CV in hopes of getting more information. That way you don't have to keep track of recruiters who likely will never get back to you.

If you are looking for a job, any job, any time, then there's no harm in sending along your CV.

Communication from recruiters is always, essentially, spam and resume collection, unless there's a clear indication that they know you, have talked to someone who does, or have provided detailed information about a named opportunity in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I being unreasonable in finding this exchange slightly rude/unprofessional, and should I broach the topic with the recruiter?

To my point of view, this does not seem unprofessional nor rude. If any, this could be some sort of scripted response (as mentioned in comments) or the recruiter may need your CV in order to get more information for you.

> Additionally should I send over my CV or press for more details about the role?

If you want to proceed with this opportunity then I suggest you send the CV.

However, I think it's ok for you to politely ask for more details as well. Consider sending your CV to the recruiter, and in that same email say something on the lines of: *"Thanks, attaching my CV. Would you mind sharing any other information you got about the position? Do you happen to know what technologies they use, or why this seems to be a perfect match with my profile? Thanks."*

Remember that sooner or later you *will* know the details and what this position involves (perhaps during interviews), and then you will be able to decide if you take it or leave it.